# Sending JSON as a parameter value for post

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, json, sinatra

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. User enters JSON in a textarea element.

   ```
   {
       "test":[
           {"a":"b"}
       ]
   }
   ```
2. Client side JavaScript parses the JSON.

   ```
   myObject = $.parseJSON($("#my-textarea").val());
   ```
3. JSON is sent over an ajax post request to the server with

   ```
   dataType: json,
   data: {"my_object": myObject}
   ```
4. Post parameters are checked on the server side in sinatra and the JSON looks like this now.

   ```
   {
       "test": {
           "0": {
               "a": "b"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

I'm wondering why the test array was changed into a hash and if there's anything I can do to avoid that. I'm thinking that the original JSON is improperly formatted, but I'm unsure.

EDIT:
Here is a stripped down version of the ajax request and controller action.

```
function test() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/test",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {"test":[{"a":"b"}]},
        success: function(response) {

        }, error:function(jqXHR,exception) {
            ajaxError(jqXHR,exception);
        }
    })
}

post '/test' do
  puts params
  return {}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stringify the resulting JSON object before you send it, like this:

```
dataType: json,
data: {"my_object": JSON.stringify(myObject)}
```

If you have to support browsers that don't have JSON natively, you can conditionally import the json js to add that support.  (jQuery does not natively have a JSON stringify method).

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably use this as a solution for now, but I'd still like to know what's going on during the request. I was under the impression that sending the object itself was better practice.

Comment: Doing `{"my_object": JSON.stringify(myObject)}` actually does send a JSON object, not text (note: it is sent as text in the actual POST of course cause that's how POST sends), the outside braces cause it to be a (new) JSON object. You could probably also just do `{JSON.stringify(myObject)}` without the key "my_object" if you wanted to (a lot of MVC implementations expect just the object, not a name=object payload).  But that depends then on what the server is expecting to receive.

Comment: I know in some cases if you don't stringify the object, it will be converted into name/value pairs, but I'm still often fuzzy as to exactly when it does what to the object.  I just almost always just stringify it cause it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var test = "{ \"test\":[{\"a\":\"b\"}]}"
$.parseJSON(test) // or even JSON.parse(test)
```

If you trace the object before it goes to the server side you will confirm that it was parsed correctly. So the problem is in sinatra I would say.

Just first check what's the parse result before doing the server call.

If you don't know if it's your client doing the bad translation, create a native javascript object (without the parse) and send it instead. If it's still bad, I doubt the problem is on the client.

Output I got on the chrome console:

```
JSON.parse(test)
  Object {test: Array[1]}
    test: Array[1]
      0: Object
```

Comment: You're correct, it gets parsed correctly before the request. It seems like the change happens during the request.

Comment: edited my answer: "If you don't know if it's your client doing the bad translation, create a native javascript object (without the parse) and send it instead. If it's still bad, I doubt the problem is on the client."

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to make the service call? And the server side handling it?

Comment: Just added them to the original post.